# I can't assign value from hiddenField into loop in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

Like in subject I have value getting from server side to hidden field and then I want to loop for this value to shows mine divs, but it didn't work (When I just input var i = 0 it normally works) Here is my code:

```
var numberOfDivs = parseInt(document.getElementById('<%= numberOfShowedDivs.ClientID %>').value);
var i = numberOfDivs;
function appendText() {
    i++;
    $("#task" + [i]).show(300);
    document.getElementById('<%= numberOfShowedDivs.ClientID %>').value = i;
}
```

What is wrong?

Comment: what do you think `[i]` means?

Comment: When did you get `numberOfDivs`?

Comment: Offtopic: you might find it easier to stick with either jquery *or* vanilla javascript.  Mixing `document.getElementById` and `$("#..")` isn't just messy; it's confusing and *will* lead to errors.

Comment: I get `numberOfDivs` from server side

Comment: You might like to create a code snippet (edit question, ctrl-M) to include some html and explain what it's supposed to do and when.  Have a read of [mcve].

Comment: You set `numberOfShowedDivs` in code behind but before this you got it in client side.

Comment: Ok I found it I add my hidden field after `<script>` tag so it can't read that value.

Comment: First client side code execute then server side code.

Comment: I think that is the opposite.

Comment: When did you set `numberOfShowedDivs`? In `PageLoad` or `click_event`?

Comment: `numberOfShowedDivs` on click event but in default is set on 0

Comment: You set default value in code behind like `numberOfShowedDivs.Value = "0"` or in markup?

Comment: in view code I set